# Use a field's value and add it to a new field in an array - Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am attempting to turn this

```
{
   "fooList" : [
      {
         "bar" : {
            "baz" : 100
         }
      },
      {
         "bar" : {
            "baz" : 200
         }
      }
   ]
},
{
   "fooList" : [
      {
         "bar" : {
            "baz" : 300
         }
      },
      {
         "bar" : {
            "baz" : 400
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

into this:

```
{
   "fooList" : [
      {
         "baz" : 100,
         "bar" : {
            "baz" : 100
         }
      },
      {
         "baz" : 200,
         "bar" : {
            "baz" : 200
         }
      }
   ]
},
{
   "fooList" : [
      {
         "baz" : 300,
         "bar" : {
            "baz" : 300
         }
      },
      {
         "baz" : 400,
         "bar" : {
            "baz" : 400
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, I really just copy `baz` and its value out of `bar`, but my issue is that is occurs within an array.

```
db.getCollection(<collection_name>).updateMany(
    {}, 
    { $set: { 'fooList.$[element].baz' : '$fooList.$[element].bar.baz' } },
    { upsert: true ,
      arrayFilters: [{'element.bar' : { $exists : true }}]
    }
)
```

But this will only set the string `$fooList.$[element].bar.baz` into baz, seen here through the results

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "fooList": [
      {
        "bar": {
          "baz": 100
        },
        "baz": "$fooList.$[element].bar.baz"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong, or if this is even possible? Thanks

Comment: The above examples are just documents in a collection if that may have not been clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using aggregation pipeline in the update in mongoDB 4.2+ as follow:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
{
$set: {
  fooList: {
    $map: {
      input: "$fooList",
      in: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$this",
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$$this.bar.baz",
                  undefined
                ]
              },
              {
                baz: "$$this.bar.baz"
              },
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  ],
 {
    multi: true
 })
```

Explained:

1. You $set $map-ping the array documents and merge based on condition where the nested element "bar.baz" exist , then you add object baz equal to the value taken from bar.baz.
2. Add multi:true to be done for all documents matching the update query filter or you can use updateMany()

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ssZNiquV2wJ)

Unfortunatelly arrayFilters are not possible when you use update with aggregation pipeline ...

For earlier mongodb versions it will look something like this:

```
   db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(d){ var newfooList=[];d.fooList.forEach(function(s){ s["baz"]=s["bar"]["baz"]; printjson(s);newfooList.push(s);  }); d["fooList"]=newfooList ; db.collection.save(d) })
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get this answer in a 4.0 version?

Comment: added an option  in my answer

Comment: That works with my version, though your first solution is really great when I can upgrade. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation that demonstrates the v4.4 "merge onto self" capability that turns `aggregate` into an `update`.   This is a useful approach when you want to process all the docs because it eliminates the "no filter" (`{}`) and `{multi:true}` bits required for `update`.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // The $map/$mergeObjects is the SAME as the answer above, just with a little
    // more compact format.  It is import to $project here, NOT $addFields, because
    // we seek to limit the pipeline to just _id (comes along automatically) and 
    // the fooList:
    {$project: {
        fooList: {$map: {
            input: "$fooList",
                in: {$mergeObjects: [
                        "$$this",
                        {$cond: [
                            {$ne: ["$$this.bar.baz", undefined]},
                            {baz: "$$this.bar.baz"},
                            {}  // else empty object                                          
                        ]}
                     ]}
        }}
    }}

    //  ...and now, using _id as the key (fast!), merge fooList back into doc:
    ,{$merge: {
        into: "foo",
        on: [ "_id" ],
        whenMatched: "merge",
        whenNotMatched: "fail"
    }}
]);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get an answer in version 4.0?